# How to block users in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using firestore database, in which there is a root collection `posts`.
To block a user I created a function in which the blocked user's user id get's stored in the sub collection of the current user id subcollection, below is the document reference

```
DocumentReference docref = Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(currentUserId).collection("blocked_ids").document(blockeduserID);
```

Now the feed is retrieved from the root collection of posts which is referred as below

```
Collection ref = Firestore.instance.collection("posts");
```

Now I want to configure the security rules for the firestore database, so that the posts of the blocked ids is  not visible to the current user.

How the security rules can be configured in this case to filter the blocked users and represent the data to the current user?

Comment: The first thing to know is that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the information, is there any other way in which I can achieve the above ? In the information shared by you I can read the queries can be filtered, how can the multiple ids be filtered in this case?

Comment: You will need to find a way to let the client filter the documents in its query, then check that filter in security rules.

Comment: What are you doing with posts? Can you just check if the user id of the post is in current viewing user's blocked list and not show it, client side?